# nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

**Overview**

I made a controller where I pass Dao through autowire and execute a query using jdbctemplate.

The controller calls the method made in dao to retrieve a table from the database.

**Code**

**Controller**

```
@Controller  
public class ManagerRoles {
    @Autowired  
    EmployeeDao dao;
    @RequestMapping("getEmployeeSchedule/{empID}")
    public ModelAndView employeeData(@PathVariable("empID")int empID,HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res,ModelMap model){
        long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();  
        Date dateStart = new Date(millis); 
        Date dateFinal = new Date(dateStart.getYear(),dateStart.getMonth(),dateStart.getDate()+30);
        System.out.println(dateStart);
        System.out.println(dateFinal);
        List<EmployeeHolidays> holidayList = dao.retrieveHolidays(dateStart, dateFinal);
        if(holidayList!=null){
        model.put("holidayList",holidayList);
        }
        System.out.println(holidayList);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
public List<EmployeeHolidays> retrieveHolidays(Date startDate,Date endDate){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM HOLIDAYS WHERE DATE >= ? AND DATE <= ? ";
        List<EmployeeHolidays> list = template.query(sql ,new RowMapper<EmployeeHolidays>(){
            public EmployeeHolidays mapRow(ResultSet rs,int rownumber) throws SQLException{
                EmployeeHolidays e = new EmployeeHolidays();
                e.setDate(rs.getDate(1));
                e.setReason(rs.getString(2));
                e.setStatus(rs.getString(3));
                return e;
            }
        });
        return list;
    }
```

The problem is that when I try to run the webapp I get the following error when I try to retrieve the table data.

> Type Exception Report
>
> Message Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.ConcurrencyFailureException:
>   StatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM HOLIDAYS WHERE DATE >= ? AND
>   DATE <= ? ]; At least one parameter to the current statement is
>   uninitialized.; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: At least one parameter to
>   the current statement is uninitialized.
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.ConcurrencyFailureException:
>   StatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM HOLIDAYS WHERE DATE >= ? AND
>   DATE <= ? ]; At least one parameter to the current statement is
>   uninitialized.; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: At least one parameter to
>   the current statement is uninitialized.
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

[image]

I checked the parameters that I am passing and both of them have values.

I don't seem to find the source of the problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `parameters` as `arguments` to the query method, look here:

```
public List<EmployeeHolidays> retrieveHolidays(Date startDate,Date endDate){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM HOLIDAYS WHERE DATE >= ? AND DATE <= ? ";
        List<EmployeeHolidays> list = template.query(
sql ,
new Object[] { startDate, endDate} //add this
new RowMapper<EmployeeHolidays>(){
            public EmployeeHolidays mapRow(ResultSet rs,int rownumber) throws SQLException{
                EmployeeHolidays e = new EmployeeHolidays();
                e.setDate(rs.getDate(1));
                e.setReason(rs.getString(2));
                e.setStatus(rs.getString(3));
                return e;
            }
        });
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I knew I missed something. Thanks for that!